# Is it possible in C++ to use ternary operator to select a comparison operator inside an if-statement?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, comparison-operators

While refactoring code to minimize the number of lines of code, I wonder if it's possible to combine two similar if-statements with the only difference being the comparison operator, e.g.

```
if (a > b) a=b;
if (a < b) a=b;
```

using the ternary operator (?) to select the comparison operator, e.g.

```
if (a (c?<:>) b) a=b;
```

My compiler doesn't throw any errors or warnings but I wonder if it really works intentionally.

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: Unless you're going for few lines as part of some kind of Code Golf challenge, short code for short code's sake is not what we should be optimizing for.

Comment: @EricPostpischil reread the first senctence. minimizing the lines of code is the goal

Comment: What compiler is that?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: You are correct, I missed that. Nonetheless, brevity and clarity are aligned up to a point, and so are brevity and optimization. Isolating the difference between two expressions can both illuminate that difference, highlight the similarities, and reduce unneeded code.

Comment: @EricPostpishil you are right, though anything can be taken too far. I removed my comment, because it was too much opinions

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::less` and `std::greater` :

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
if(c ? std::less<int>{}(a, b) : std::greater<int>{}(a, b))
  a = b;
```

Do note that this is considered bad practice because it's quite unreadable and thus shouldn't be used in production code unless there's a particular reason.

Comment: See also [std::min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max).

Comment: How is this different from `c ? a<b : a>b`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil It isn't, thats kind of the idea since that code construct should be illegal according to the standard, and this one isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Solution with lambdas:

```
const auto lt = [](int a, int b) { return a < b; };
const auto gt = [](int a, int b) { return a > b; };

if ((c ? +lt : +gt)(a, b))
    a = b;
```

`+` converts lambda into a function pointer, so `+less` and `+greater` have the same type.

Answer (score 3):

A C++17 way:

```
if (auto s = 2 * !!c - 1; s * a > s * b) a = b;
```

`s` is the sign of `c`, and multiplying `a` and `b` by `s` when it's `-1` effectively reverses `>`. One hazard though is the attempted negation of a 2's complement signed type currently at the minimum.

Comment: `if (const auto& [lhs, rhs] = (c ? std::tie(a, b) : std::tie(b, a)); lhs < rhs) a = b;`

Answer (score 2):

No. `<` and `>` are operators, not expressions. Operator `?:` takes 3 expressions.

> The conditional operator expressions have the form `E1 ? E2 : E3`
>
> The first operand of the conditional operator is evaluated and contextually converted to bool. After both the value evaluation and all side effects of the first operand are completed, if the result was true, the second operand is evaluated. If the result was false, the third operand is evaluated.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting, however it's interesting that my compiler accepts it anyway.

Comment: @epp: What insane compiler is that?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a ternary operator here, but rather a plain old boring condition for `if`:

```
if ( (c && a < b) || (!c && a > b) ) a = b;
```

I admit, wether this is more readable than something else is up to the reader to decide.

Comment: I guess the comparison should be done based on the value of c. I don't see a c here.

Comment: @MutableSideEffect now I understand why nobody proposed it before ;)

Comment: @MutableSideEffect now there is a `c` :)

Comment: missing a closing `)`

Answer (score 1):

From your example, I would simply do

```
a = (c ? std::max(a, b) : std::min(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetics to the rescue!!!

```cpp
if((a-b)*(((int) c)*2 - 1) < 0)
    a=b;
```

I hope the `<` is the right way round.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I can suggest the following syntax:

```
if (a, cmp(c, std::less{}, std::greater{}), b) ...
```

as an approximation to

```
if (a (c ? < : >) b) ...
```

Implementation:

```
template<class True, class False>
class cmp {
public:
    cmp(bool flag, True if_true, False if_false)
        : flag_(flag), if_true_(if_true), if_false_(if_false) {}       

private:
    template<class Lhs>
    class Proxy {
    public:
        Proxy(const Lhs& lhs, cmp comparator) 
            : lhs_(lhs), comparator_(comparator) {}

        template<class Rhs>
        bool operator,(const Rhs& rhs) {
            if (comparator_.flag_)
                return comparator_.if_true_(lhs_, rhs);
            else
                return comparator_.if_false_(lhs_, rhs);
        }

    private:
        const Lhs& lhs_;
        const cmp comparator_;
    };

    template<class Lhs>
    friend auto operator,(const Lhs& lhs, cmp comparator) {
        return Proxy<Lhs>(lhs, comparator);
    }

    const bool flag_;
    const True if_true_;
    const False if_false_;
};
```